# How to save the value of a variable after initialization

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a LiveData variable that increases it's value by 1 every time a user triggers certain events.

I want to save the value, so for example if the user triggered 1 event and closed the app and reopened it the variable value stays 1 instead of resetting to the initial value of 0 every time my ViewModel get recreated.

```
    private val counter = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply {
        value = 0
    }

    fun counterPlus(){
        counter.value = _counter.value!!.plus(1)
    }
```

Comment: You should look into datastore, which is the replacement for shared-preferences https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#0

Comment: Alternatively, if the use is only during app usage you could create a companion object in the MainActivity and access it globally.

Comment: @Balbinator Can you elaborate more on the companion object approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save your data to persistent storage. There are three common options in Android: Files, SQLite database and SharedPreferences. For your use case, maybe SharedPreferences - which is a `key-value` type of storage mechanism - is a good option due to its simplicity.

Once you decide on that, the next step is to find a place/moment to save your data to the storage.

You could save in `onPause` and load in `onResume` for example, assuming you decide to go with SPs:

```
// In on pause
context.getSharedPreferences(...).edit().putInt("myValueKey", counter.value).apply();
```

To load, the procedure is very similar:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(...).getInt("myValueKey", defaultValue)
```

Check https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#kotlin

Comment: Better use Preferences DataStore see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075575/android-benefits-of-datastore-over-sharedpreferences